# Java factory method call from Scala

Tags: java, scala, design-patterns, factory-pattern

In a Scala project I am working on I am using a library that provides a factory method to instantiate instance of crypto-currencies exchanges interfaces. in java it is like this :

```
Exchange bitstamp = ExchangeFactory.INSTANCE.createExchange(BitstampExchange.class.getName());
```

and it works, in scala I tried to call it like this :

```
 val exchange = ExchangeFactory.INSTANCE.createExchange(classOf[BitstampExchange].toString);
```

but I get an exception and it doesn't work.

```
[ExchangeException: Problem creating Exchange (class not found)]
```

now, I don't really know the best way to deal with. Should I write my own factory method in scala ? or is there some workaround to make it work ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try `val exchange : Exchange` ?

Comment: Why did you use `toString` in Scala version? `Class.toString` and `Class.getName` have different outputs. For example, `classOf[Integer].toString` equals to `class java.lang.Integer`, but `classOf[Integer].getName` equals to `java.lang.Integer` (note the absence of "class" word). For other types (e.g. nested classes) it will be even more different. I suspect this is the reason of your error.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir Matveev, using .getName solved the problem for me.

Comment: Vladimir's response here should really be the answer.